# How would I convert this string into a list where the spaces are also separate items?

Tags: python, list

```
code = ("1 2 3 4")  
b = code.split()  
print(b)
```

This code returns `['1','2','3','4']` when I want it to return `['1',' ','2', '3',' ','4']`. How would I do that?

Comment: What if there were two digit numbers in there? Or do you want just all characters?

Comment: how would you format ["10 11 12 13"] ?

Comment: What about if there are runs of multiple spaces? Do you want those to be captured as a single string with multiple spaces, as a separate string for each space, or…?

Comment: Also, why does your desired output not have a space between `2` and `3`?

Comment: looks like someone didn't expect 4 comments and 3 answers in minutes :)

Comment: He / She had a warm welcome to stackoverflow, @Jean-FrançoisFabre :)

Comment: if only the example & expected output was edited for clarity that would deserve more votes.

Comment: Half the answers are just duplicates of Noskio's deleted answer that only works for single-digit values…

Comment: If only an answer was chosen as the preferred one... :) @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you want to split *words*, not *characters* (otherwise `list(code)` would decompose that for you).

use `re.split` preserving split char by wrapping the split regex between parentheses:

```
import re
code = "1 2 3 4"

print(re.split("( )",code))
```

result:

```
['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3', ' ', '4']
```

make it `re.split("(\s+)",code)` if you want to match more than 1 space, tabs, etc...

Comment: That's clever. Only knew `findall` yielded captured groups if present.

Comment: that's a lesser-known feature of `re.split`. But I'd prefer the question to be clearer if you ask me, because I'm not 100% sure it answers :)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> code.replace(' ', ', ,').split(',')
['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3', ' ', '4']
```

Comment: Haha creative ;)

Comment: Makes me smile, great! :) but will not work in case of double spaces.

Comment: @Pitto.. You have keen eyes. We can fix it by doing something like `code.replace(' ', ', ,').replace(',,', ',').split(',')` when there are multiple spaces, but lets not over complicate :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a readable and easy approach without importing any library

```
code = ("1 2 3 4")
b = []

for element in code.split():
    b.append(element)
    b.append(" ")

del b[-1]

print b
```

Comment: Make sure to remove the last element of `c` in order to remove the last space that gets appended.

Comment: 100% right, @LukeBordonaro!
I missed that in the request, fixed now :)

Comment: `element != code[-1]` only works if there are no duplicate characters anywhere in the string, and if the last chunk is only a single character long. So, while this does happen to work for the example, it's a pretty misleading answer. (If you just want something that only works for the example, you can just do `b = ["1", " ", "2", " ", "3", " ", "4"]` and be done with it.)

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? It answers the OP's question and also builds up on what OP knows--> split()

Comment: I've made a mistake in my previous version and... I paid for it :)
@Bayko

Comment: @Bayko Wasn't me, but it is a bit clunky (there are way more elegant ways) and it is not really a general approach, e.g. it would remove additional spaces between tokens.

Comment: If we do not have specs (e.g. is a single space expected or should we take care of tabs too?) it is hard to say what is better and what is not.
We are just building on our idea of a general implementation but, imho, we should just fullfill op's request.
Why not putting in some error handling, for example?
Because it was not requested.

I think that this concept is also correctly underlined also by the author of current best answer in his comment : "I'd prefer the question to be clearer if you ask me, because I'm not 100% sure it answers "

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [x for y in code.split() for x in (y, ' ')][:-1]
['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3', ' ', '4']
```

Or

```
>>> from itertools import cycle,chain
>>> list(chain(*zip(code.split(), cycle(' '))))[:-1]
['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3', ' ', '4']
```

Comment: Love the list comprehension

Comment: Can you please point me to any book / exercise that can help me to write such nice list comprehensions? 
I am really finding a hard time to understand them well, @sunitha

Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: @Pitto. stackoverflow is probably the best place. Try to work out an answer for the questions posted in your own way, try to then simplify it, finally compare your answer with  other answers,  people have posted

Answer (score 1):

Someone posted this and deleted it, but this works quite simply. `list()` will give you a list of an iterable.

```
code = ("1 2 3 4")
b = list(code)
print(b)

['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3', ' ', '4']
```

Comment: yeah, but OP probably wants to be able to handle multiple-digit numbers, well, we don't know that for sure yet...

Comment: Also if you have more than one space between numbers it will generate a wrong output.

Comment: It works if you want to separate spaces or multi-digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert it to list

```
code = ("1 2 3 4")
b = list(code)
print(b)
```

Note:- if you have 2 digit no. It will also split those numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
code = ("1 2 3 4")  
list(code)
```